# No IntelliSense in SSMS 2008 for Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, intellisense, ssms

I'm building a Table Valued Function in SSMS, and I'm expecting IntelliSense to help me select columns, but it doesn't. Consider this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.My_TVF
(   
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT [PO].I -- Here I is my cursor, ctrl+space does nothing
    FROM dbo.SomePurchaseOrderView PO
    JOIN dbo.SomePurchaseOrderLineView POL ON PO.PO_NUM = POL.PO_NUM
    WHERE  PO.PO_NUM IN (
        SELECT TOP 500 PO_NUM 
        FROM dbo.SomeTable 
        WHERE PROCESSED = 0
    )
)
GO
```

I want it to suggest column names for the `select` clause.

Notes:

- The cache is fresh (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
- IntelliSense works fine in general, this is the only situation I've encountered where it doesn't.
- I'm querying a view instead of a table, if it matters.

I know it often fails when there is some kind of syntax error in what you are writing, but I can execute my query just fine when I specify a column.

Comment: @vote-to-close-er: **"unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"**. Please.

Comment: did you do this? `Use DB go` ?

Comment: Have you just created the function new since your SSMS session connected to this server?  If so, be aware that SSMS Intellisense will not pick anything created or changed since your first connection to the server instance.  Easiest way to fix that is to restart SSMS.

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 (good thing _this_ intellisense works): no, I have not, and I don't see how it would make a difference. Everything involved is on the same database

Comment: @RBarryYoung I've restarted SSMS, went to modify the function, and it still didn't work. Anyway, wouldn't refreshing the IntelliSense cache do the same?

Comment: I can tell you that it works in SQL Server 2014.If It matters to you.

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2291/enabling-intellisense-and-refreshing-intellisense-data-in-ssms-2008/

Comment: @D.J. This along with the answer from CoolWilly makes me think that they fixed this after 2008.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Intellisense was first introduced in SQL Server 2008. So it is possible that they fixed that in 2012.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Troubleshooting IntelliSense in SQL Server Management: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On msdn it says: "IntelliSense is available for the SELECT statement when it is coded by itself, but not when the SELECT is contained in a CREATE FUNCTION statement."
Although, when testing it in my SSMS 2012, it does seem to work...

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934481.aspx
(sorry, I don't have enough rep for a comment...)

Comment: Good find, I don't know whether that is **the** explanation though.

Comment: IMHO, I think it is.
If you are also looking for a workaround, next to the explanation from Microsoft, then you can always create the `SELECT` statement first (outside of the `CREATE FUNCTION`), where Intellisense is available. Then put it back in the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement :)

Comment: yeah that makes sense as a workaround. Perhaps they indeed changed this after SSMS 2008. I'm not going to accept your answer until after the bounty, but you got it unless someone else shows up with something better.

Comment: I just discovered that when I hover over any of the fields in my SQL `SELECT`, a tooltip appears that reads `CREATE FUNCTION is not currently supported in Transact-SQL IntelliSense`. Weird! So your answer is definitely right.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a blog posted by Pinal Dave on SQL Server Authority related intellisense. 
Here's the link: 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/31/sql-server-2008-intellisense-does-not-work-enable-intellisense/

Follow the below steps from the blog:

```
1) Make sure you are connected to SQL Server 2008 Edition. 
2) IntelliSense should be enabled.
    a) From Toolbar
    b) Go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> IntelliSense
3) IntelliSense should be refreshed with the latest changes in database.
    a) Press CTRL+SHIFT+R
    b) Go to Edit >> IntelliSense >> Refresh Local Cache
4) Go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> General >> IntelliSense
```

Comment: I've specified in my question that intellisense works fine elsewhere, it's just this exact situation when creating a TVF.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few assumptions:

1. You are connected to the right SQL Server that has the tables listed in query below.
2. You are not using index hints. I have had problems with intellisense and index hints.

I was able to reproduce the problem on my computer, looks like you need to type a comma before SSMS will suggest the next column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.My_TVF
(   
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT [PO].I X -- If you press ctrl+space at the location of X it does nothing
                    -- since it has already suggested that column, PO.I (that's my assumption)
                    -- for next columns type a comma after PO.I and press ctrl+space.
                    -- I had no problems getting suggestions for other columns.
    FROM dbo.SomePurchaseOrderVIEW PO
    JOIN dbo.SomePurchaseOrderLineView POL ON PO.PO_NUM = POL.PO_NUM
    WHERE  PO.PO_NUM IN (
        SELECT TOP 500 PO_NUM 
        FROM dbo.SomeTable 
        WHERE PROCESSED = 0
    )
)
GO
```

Comment: OK sorry if the `I` confused you, that was just to simulate my cursor being at that point. Otherwise I know it would not work...

Comment: Is `PO.I` not a valid column on your table? I assumed that was a valid column and you are not getting suggestions for other columns on the table.

So, typing `PO.` and pressing ctrl+space does nothing?

Does typing a comma and then pressing ctrl+space not work too?

Comment: typing `PO.` and pressing ctrl+space does nothing indeed. It doesn't work for further columns (after commas) either.